# Synapse serverless sql script working for individual views but not on joins

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, serverless, azure-synapse

Currently we have a serverless databse in synapse with below config and blob data contributor role to Storage
[image]

**Issue**: Individual select statement working for views created on serverless database but if they are used as joins, itsgiving error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Individual select statement working for views created on serverless database but if they are used as joins, its giving error.

By looking at your error it seems like it is because the managed identity of synapse workspace doesn't have permission on the storage account.

1. Select  **Access control (IAM)**.
2. Select  **Add**  >  **Add role assignment**  to open the Add role assignment page.
3. Assign the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` assign to `MANAGEDIDENTITY` select synapse workspace managed identity name.
4. Select  **Save**  to add the role assignment.

I tried to reproduce the similar issue in my environment, but it is working fine for me with sample data.

**Sample Code:** For creation view

```sql
CREATE  MASTER  KEY  ENCRYPTION  BY  PASSWORD = 'AnkitaAnkush@29';
GO

CREATE  DATABASE  SCOPED  CREDENTIAL SynapseIdentity1
WITH  IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity';
GO
CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA  SOURCE mysample2
WITH ( LOCATION = 'https://dlsg2p.dfs.core.windows.net/fsn2p',
CREDENTIAL = SynapseIdentity1
)

CREATE  VIEW file4v as  SELECT  top(100) * FROM  OPENROWSET
( BULK  '/file3.csv'
, FORMAT = 'CSV'
, PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
, HEADER_ROW = True
, DATA_SOURCE = 'mysample1'
) AS [cc];
```

**Execution:**

[image]